# How to use routes in Shopify app built using Shopify CLI , React and Shopify App Bridge

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, shopify, shopify-app-bridge

I have a problem with using routes in my application, it is a template built using Shopify CLI, React and Shopify App Bridge guided by [this documentation here](https://shopify.dev/apps/tools/cli/getting-started).

Every route I trigger does get sent to the _app.js file within my project as I can log most of the output in the console, but I can't get it to actually include paths of subpages in my apps like `https://{apphost}/custompage` will not navigate to custompage but an error handler and the custompage gets included in the query. The route and pathname fields of the props return

```
{ 
  ...
  router: "_error",
  pathname: "_error ",
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
{ 
  ...
  router: "custompage",
  pathname: "custompage",
  ...
}
```

I expected the above to be the result but it isn't. But the custompage url does however appear in the asPath field like this `asPath: "/custompage?hmac={hmac}&host={host}&shop={shop}"` pretend everything in {} has actual information.

The query field gets the fields it needs as it does on a working page. So the main issue is just routing.

With this in mind I have concluded that maybe I have issues on my side and triggering the server side routes handler, but I do not know where to start redirecting to exact pages instead of the index page that came with the boilerplate code. And I looked on their documentation but they skip most parts that are required to actually explain handling routing with their boiletplate codes. I do not want to edit major functions because I am worried they might stop the whole app from working but I need to be able to handle routes on the app without getting the `An unexpected error has occurred.` error when trying to route to subpages. Even extensions to whitelisted urls within my app trigger that error, so I think I need help with adding routing to the app or server.

Can anyone help me figure out what I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I am still new to Shopify but I can say that working with Shopify is a nightmare.

I am not sure if this is the final solution but for now this works: make sure that all the files you are trying to route to have the same naming as your path.
If you are routing to  `https://{appURL}/subpath`  then your JS file should be  `subpath.js` . I currently can only get it to work if the file is in the same folder as my _app.js. If I move the file from  `./subpath`  to  `/dir/subpath`   then I need to change the extension to  `https://{appURL}/dir/subpath`  in my Shopify app settings. It seems to operate relative to the _app.js file's location so keep that in mind.

If you used the Shopify CLI and  `shopify node create`  to create your app then this could help with your routing 400 headache.

Comment: I am still looking for a better way around this as having everything in the parent folder could lead to a cluttered folder. I prefer using the components folder for pages. I will update as soon as I get one.